# Can multiple objects be associated with a single imageview XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose that I create an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) for an image, can the same id be used for creating multiple instances of the image in the screen?

That is, suppose I want to create 10 balls on the screen, is it enough that I define the XML for one ball and then can it be used repetitively for creation of 10 balls?

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the same view as many times as you want. The only problem is that all views have same id and if they belong to the same parent view then you can only access the first view using `findViewById()` inside your code. You might want to use ListView in that case.